# How to use Spark to read data from one AWS account and write to another AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop

I have spark jobs running on a EKS cluster to ingest AWS logs from S3 buckets.
Now I have to ingest logs from another AWS account. I have managed to use the below setting to successfully read in data from cross account with hadoop AssumedRoleCredentialProvider.
But how do I save the dataframe back to my own AWS account S3? It seems no way to set the Hadoop S3 config back to my own AWS account.

```
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.assumed.role.external.id","****")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider","org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.AssumedRoleCredentialProvider")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.assumed.role.credentials.provider","com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.assumed.role.arn","****")
val data = spark.read.json("s3a://cross-account-log-location")
data.count

//change back to InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider not working
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider","com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider")
data.write.parquet("s3a://bucket-in-my-own-aws-account")
```

Comment: Have you have configured your source bucket (in the source account) and the IAM user (on destination account) to allow the cross-account traffic? (https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/copy-s3-objects-account/)

Comment: @CesarA.Mostacero Thanks for the link, but my use case doesn't allow us to sync the logs over to our account from source account due to cost concerns (although it'd be much easier if the logs are in our account). We can only assume a role in Spark context to reach the source account to read in the data (which is successful with above config). But after that I don't know how to proceed to save the data in this dataframe back to our destination account since the connection established is with the source account.

Comment: The link was more regarding the IAM user configuration that is required to work, in that example, with an s3 cli command but cross-accounts. I was thinking that, similarly that it is described there, setup the IAM user that you use to run your spark job on aws

Comment: @IvanDing Were you able to get this to work? Wondering what the solution was for InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider and TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider combination in same spark job.

Answer (score 3):

As per the hadoop documentation different S3 buckets can be accessed with different S3A client configurations, having a per bucket configuration including the bucket name.

> `Eg: fs.s3a.bucket.<bucket name>.access.key`

Check the below URL: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#Configurations_different_S3_buckets